# Slide out menu using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a slide out menu on click of a button by using only Javascript. I know many solutions exist, but all of them use jQuery. I want to code it exclusively using Javascript. Can someone please help me with it?

**HTML**

```
<li class="menu"><a href="#about" id="mainmenu">Menu<span class="box-shadow-menu"></span></a>
    <ul class="sub" id="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#sub
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #662D91;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 238px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}
#sub a
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.05 );
}
```

It should slide from right end towards left. And also the Menu element should also be present when slide out occurs.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily with css transitions, no need for jquery or any other libraries, no need to even do animations by javascript.
I have created a simple example of slide in/out submenu: http://jsfiddle.net/pisamce/97x76otx/
Javascript is used to toggle css class, and animations are done by css.

```js
var menubtn = document.getElementById('mainmenu');
var sub = document.getElementById('sub');
menubtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var closed = sub.className.indexOf('closed') !== -1;
    if (closed) {
        sub.className = sub.className.replace('closed', 'open');
    } else {
        sub.className = sub.className.replace('open', 'closed');
    }
});
```

```css
.sub {
    position: absolute;
}
.open {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, 0, 0.265, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
}
.closed {
    left:-100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, 0, 0.265, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
}
```

```html
<li class="menu"><a href="#about" id="mainmenu">Menu<span class="box-shadow-menu"></span></a> 
    </ul>
    <ul class="sub closed" id="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested. But its still not working
http://jsfiddle.net/SaloniDesai/k2enwb2n/

Comment: How is it not working? You need to modify your original css, for example, remove: `display: none;` from your `#sub` style.

Comment: Here, I have modified your css just a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/k2enwb2n/2/

Comment: One last question. Is it possible to make the #mainmenu element of same width like its child #sub element?